# Duplicate zip entry when creating an obfuscated application jar using proguard with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, proguard, obfuscation

The Java application itself contains no third party library dependencies. And if I remove the `obfuscate` task and the line `jar.finalizedBy(project.tasks.obfuscate)`, the standard jar builds and is runnable.

Error ..

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':obfuscate'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/rob/git/repo/build/libs/tool.out.jar] (Can't read [/Users/rob/git/repo/build/libs/tool.jar] (Duplicate zip entry [com/example/cli/j.class == tool.jar:com/example/cli/HelperUtils$5.class]))
```

`build.gradle` ..

```
task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {
    configuration 'proguard.txt'

  injars "build/libs/tool.jar"
  outjars "build/libs/tool.out.jar"
  libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
}

jar {
    archiveName = "tool.jar"
    from sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    include '**/cli/*.class'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.cli.Tool'
    }
}
jar.finalizedBy(project.tasks.obfuscate)
```

`proguard.txt` ..

```
-keep public class com.example.cli.* {*;}
```

The application contains 3 Java class files ..

```
com.example.cli.Tool (which contains the main)
com.example.cli.HelperUtils
com.example.cli.CustomEnums
```

Comment: Double check tool.jar to make sure it does not have duplicate entries.  Note: many tools tolerate and hide duplicate entries.  You might need to look at the jar using a hex editor to see the duplicate entry.

Comment: when you say "duplicate entry", do you mean a custom class defined twice?

Comment: A duplicate entry would be any entry of the JAR which was stored twice using the same entry name.  ("stored" instead of "defined" because class resources are stored in a JAR file, whereas classes are defined during class loading.  A JAR might store a class resource having the same name twice, but a class loader should only ever define a particular named class at most once.)

Comment: Duplicate entries are possible depending on the tool or API which was used to create the JAR.  A lot of tools allow new entries to be added to an existing JAR without making sure the new entries are not duplicates of already present entries.

Comment: Unfortunately, tools for *viewing* jars often ignore duplicate entries.  Typically, a single table of entries will be generated, and a duplicate entry will just overwrite a previously stored entry.  You have to either use a hex editor and look for duplicate names, or do something like extract the jar contents and look for overwrite warnings from the tool output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following to the `jar` task:

```
jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    ..
}
```